# Is it okay to say “sich in das Pyjama einwickeln” in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Can one say *sich in das Pyjama einwickeln* in German? I would like to avoid the word *schlüpfen* in this phrase, as I am using it in another part of the sentence.

Comment: Nur wenn Du den Pyjama als Decke benutzt.

Comment: Pyjama is male (der Pyjama), so it should be »sich in *den* Pyjama einwickeln«. What is wrong with »schlüpfen«? »Einwickeln« would mean: »to wrap the pajama around the body (without putting it on)«, so your arms and legs would not be inside the pajamas arms and legs.

Answer (score 6):

Wenn Du "schlüpfen" nicht benutzen willst, nimm doch "anziehen": Man zieht den Pyjama (Schlafanzug) an.

Answer (score 4):

From its etymology of persian **pā** (*foot*) and **jāma** (long garment) "[Pyjama](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=pyjama)" is used for nightwear made of a shirt and **trousers**.

Therefore the use of *einwickeln* (to wrap) is not very common. Instead we may use other verbs such as: **anziehen**, **hineinschlüpfen**, **anlegen**, **überstreifen**, **sich bekleiden mit**, **sich kleiden in**, **überziehen** and more.

Alternatives to nightwear include: **Nachthemd** (single long shirt without trousers), **Schlafanzug** (if made of tricot fabric but it can be used for a *Pyjama* as well), **Strampler** (romper suit for a baby), **Nachtwäsche** (technical term in clothing industry).

The predominant grammatical gender for *Pyjama* is masculine (though neuter may be used as well).

Comment: I don't think it's very relevant that "sich in den Pyjama einwickeln" is uncommon, but that it has a completely different meaning than "... anziehen".

Answer (score 3):

First, in this sentence you would not use "das Pyjama" but "den Pyjama" (don't ask me which of the 4 cases it is, I believe Akkusativ, but I am not sure).

Second, the word "einwickeln" means more wrap around, so if you want to express that the person actually wears an Pyjama (as opposed to being wrapped in the fabric the pyjama is made of), you would not use this.

Comment: Ich würde auch *der Pyjama* sagen, aber der Duden gibt *das* als Alternative an.

Comment: Akkusativ ist hier richtig: sich in wen oder was einwickeln -> Akkusativ.